# Display date only once for a each set of posts relating to that date

Tags: loop, date, timestamp

The following loop works great for me in getting posts with a given date with the use of the_time(...):

```
<?php
    $myPost = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    ));
    while ($myPost->have_posts()): $myPost->the_post();
?>

<div class="timeline-group">
<p class="modified-time"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></p>
<h5><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h5>
</div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    //Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

But the first 10 posts always show the same date (i.e. July 21, 2017).  I want to display that date only once for these 10 posts. And if I create a new post tomorrow, then it should then show a new date under these 10 posts, and then the post associating to that new date.  How can I transform my loop to think that way without hard-coding dates?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `the_date()`, it has this as a built-in feature.

See the [dev docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/) for more info.

Comment: You're welcome. To some devs it looks like a bug at first, but for your case it's a nice feature ;-)

Comment: @birgire Like when I tried to show the date twice for two days, then finally realized that `the_date()` intentionally only shows it once.

Comment: happened to me too ;-) @JackJohansson

Answer (score 1):

You can save the last date on a variable and on each iteration you compare the current date with the last date, and just write the date if they're different:

```
<?php
    $myPost = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    ));
    $lastDate = '';
    while ($myPost->have_posts()): $myPost->the_post();
    $currentDate = get_the_time('F j, Y');
?>

<?php if($currentDate != $lastDate): ?>
    <h2><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></h2>
    <?php $lastDate = $currentDate; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="timeline-group">
<h5><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h5>
</div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    //Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```